# Formatting NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
// calculate elapsed time
NSTimeInterval elapsed = currentTime - startTime;

int mins = (int) (elapsed / 60.0);
elapsed -= mins * 60;
int secs = (int) (elapsed);
elapsed -= secs;
int fraction = elapsed * 10.0;

// update time label using format 0:00:0
returnTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u:%02u.%u",mins,secs,fraction];
```

This currently outputs 0:00.0

How would I output 00:00.00 and have it increment every hundredth of a second instead of 10th of a second?

Comment: Make the 1st and 3rd format specifier like your 2nd. `%02u`.

Comment: And that would be hundredth of a second, not millisecond. You need three decimals for milliseconds. And multiple by 100, not 10.

Comment: For milliseconds you'd multiply fractional seconds by 1000.  And use `%03u`.

Comment: @rmaddy when I use %02u for the third one (the one that should output every hundredth of a second, it does this 00:00.01, 00:00.02... 00:00.09...00:01.01. It never increments the 2nd to last digit

Comment: What is your multiplier??

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect answer.  Long day.  Deleted.

Comment: Also, you don't need to split `elapsed` into integral (`secs`) and decimal (`fraction`) parts as `printf` can do the job. Use `%06.3f` to print `elapsed` as a 6 characters long decimal number padded with `0`, with 3 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
returnTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%05.2f",
    (int)(elapsed/60), fmod(elapsed, 60)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `0n` in the format specifier to zero-pad the length of the number displayed to `n` digits (where n is a positive integer), e.g.,

```
unsigned int seconds = elapsed;
unsigned int hundredths = (elapsed - seconds) * 100.0;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u.%02u", (seconds/60), (seconds%60), hundredths]
```

Comment: this appears to work, except that the very last digit (hundredths place) only seems to vacillate between 0,7. In comparison to the native iOS Stopwatch app, it vacillates between 0-9, albeit extremely quickly. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Perhaps the stopwatch app refreshes at a higher frequency, or cheats and has a fixed animation for the last digits rather than showing the real values until stopped…